# Redmine upgrated to 2.4: Error on startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, redmine

I have upgraded my redmine version to 2.4 on an Ubuntu 12.06 LTS server.

I followed the up gradation steps mentioned [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade).

But even after restarting my apache server when I access the redmine URL `http://server/redmine` I am getting the below error:

**Can anyone help me with this. Where am I going wrong!? I am kinda new to working with ruby on rails.**

[image: ERROR ON STARTUP]

My **preintializer.rb** file:

```
begin
require "rubygems"
require "bundler"
rescue LoadError
 $stderr.puts "Redmine requires Bundler. Please install it with `gem install bundler`."
exit 1
end

if Gem::Version.new(Bundler::VERSION) < Gem::Version.new("1.0.21")
  $stderr.puts "Redmine requires Bundler 1.0.21 (you're using #  {Bundler::VERSION}).\nPlease install a newer version with `gem install bundler`."
exit 1
end

begin
ENV["BUNDLE_GEMFILE"] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile", __FILE__)
Bundler.setup
rescue Bundler::GemNotFound
$stderr.puts "Some gems may need to be installed or updated.\nPlease run `bundle install --without development test`."
exit 1
end
```

My **environment.rb** file:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Make sure there's no plugin in vendor/plugin before starting
vendor_plugins_dir = File.join(Rails.root, "vendor", "plugins")
if Dir.glob(File.join(vendor_plugins_dir, "*")).any?
  $stderr.puts "Plugins in vendor/plugins (#{vendor_plugins_dir}) are no longer allowed. " +
"Please, put your Redmine plugins in the `plugins` directory at the root of your " +
"Redmine directory (#{File.join(Rails.root, "plugins")})"
 exit 1
end

# Initialize the rails application
RedmineApp::Application.initialize!
```

I have installed `bundler`.

**LOCAL GEMS**

```
actionmailer (4.0.2, 3.2.16, 2.3.14)
actionpack (4.0.2, 3.2.16, 2.3.14)
activemodel (4.0.2, 3.2.16)
activerecord (4.0.2, 3.2.16, 2.3.14)
activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
activeresource (4.0.0, 3.2.16, 2.3.14)
activesupport (4.0.2, 3.2.16, 2.3.14)
arel (5.0.0, 4.0.1, 3.0.3)
atomic (1.1.14)
bigdecimal (1.2.3, 1.1.0)
builder (3.2.2, 3.1.4, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.3.5)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
capybara (2.1.0)
childprocess (0.3.9)
coderay (1.1.0)
database_cleaner (1.2.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.2.6)
ffi (1.9.3)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.6.9)
io-console (0.4.2, 0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.3)
json (1.8.1, 1.5.5)
mail (2.5.4)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (2.0, 1.25.1)
mini_portile (0.5.2)
minitest (5.0.8, 4.7.5, 2.5.1)
mocha (0.14.0)
multi_json (1.8.2)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.14)
net-ldap (0.3.1)
nokogiri (1.6.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5, 1.1.6)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-openid (1.4.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.0.2, 3.2.16, 2.3.14)
rails-observers (0.1.2)
railties (4.0.2, 3.2.16)
rake (10.1.0, 0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
rdoc (4.0.1, 3.12.2, 3.9.5)
ruby-openid (2.3.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rubygems-update (2.1.11, 1.8.25)
rvm (1.11.3.8)
sprockets (2.10.1, 2.2.2)
sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
thor (0.18.1)
thread_safe (0.1.3)
tilt (2.0.0, 1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (1.1.0, 0.3.38)
xpath (2.0.0)
```